# See if getValues() is all no value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a huge range of cells I need to see if they have no value.  I know that I could use isBlank, but the cells have formulas in them, so isBlank returns false.  Is there a way to check an array of cells for no value quickly?

```
function mp4fix(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
//hide rows automatically
//var c will be a for loop eventually
var c = 80;
var accomm = sheet.getSheetByName("MP4").getRange(c,1,20,1).isBlank();
var academ = sheet.getSheetByName("MP4").getRange(c+22,1,2,1).isBlank();
var behavi = sheet.getSheetByName("MP4").getRange(c+25,1,2,1).isBlank();
if(accomm=="true" && academ=="true" && behavi=="true"){
    sheet.getSheetByName("MP4").hideRows(c-5,31);
  }
}
```

These cells have reference formulas in them (i.e. ='MP3'!A80), so the isBlank is coming back false, even though the formula is returning no value.

Comment: can you try isBlank() on a single cell with your formula that is returning no value? I have tried it on my end, it is returning true on a cell with no actual value but has formula referencing to a cell from another sheet. It shouldn't be able to catch the formula. If possible can you share a copy of your spreadsheet? (please remove any sensitive data).

Comment: @DanF the single cell worked and came back true.  This had me go look at each cell and some of them had a space in them, which is why it was reporting false for the range.  Thanks so much for the debugging help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function mp4fix() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("MP4");
  var c = 80;
  var accomm = sh.getRange(c, 1, 20, 1).isBlank();
  var academ = sh.getRange(c + 22, 1, 2, 1).isBlank();
  var behavi = sh.getRange(c + 25, 1, 2, 1).isBlank();
  if (accomm && academ && behavi) {
    sh.hideRows(c - 5, 31);
  }
}
```

"true" and "false" are strings true  and false are booleans